# Communication between Chrome Extension and Android Device

Tags: android, google-chrome-extension

The question is that i have a project like a QrCode Login base.
There are a few steps that i already that what is the direction i have to take, like the android apk search in the database if the user exists or the generation of a QrCode in the extension, but the communication between the Extension and the android Device i really don't know.
Can anybody give me some directions about this communication?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Could you be more specific as to what you don't know?  Thanks!

Comment: chrome extensions are more like html, js pages, think of interactions between a webpage and an app.

Comment: Thanks for both anwsers.
Qantas 94 Heavy the thing is that is there a way to pass some data from a android app to a extension browser?
Example: My app sending login credentials store in my device and i pass it that credentials into the facebook so that i don't have to type it.
A example of that i'm trying to do is this but not so complex
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsS52PpF-x8
thanks in advance